# Issue posting to multiple clients

Tags: java, sockets, hashmap

Hey guys i've just recently been getting a hang of sockets but ran into an issue with posting to multiple clients. Ive made it multithreaded to handle this and am attempting to hold all client data the server needs to send to in a hashmap, however when cycling and adding to the hashmap. it seems to only ever add one person. Heres the code..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class HostMain extends Thread {

/**
 * The set of all names of clients in the chat room.  Maintained
 * so that we can check that new clients are not registering name
 * already in use.
 */
private static HashMap<String, ConnectedUsers> users = new HashMap<String, ConnectedUsers>();

public HostMain() throws IOException
{

}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
    System.err.println("SERVER:The chat server is running.");
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    System.err.println("SERVER:socket created");
    Constants.getInstance().getStatusLabel().setText("Server is running. Join when ready");
    try {
        while (true) {

            System.err.println("SERVER:New handler being created");
            new Handler(listener.accept()).start();

        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Constants.getInstance().getStatusLabel().setText("SERVER:A HOST IS ALREADY RUNNING ON THIS PORT!");
        System.err.println("SERVER:A HOST IS ALREADY RUNNING ON THIS PORT!");
    }
}
/**
 * The port that the server listens on.
 */
private static final int PORT = 1337;




/**
 * The appplication main method, which just listens on a port and
 * spawns handler threads.
 */

/**
 * A handler thread class.  Handlers are spawned from the listening
 * loop and are responsible for a dealing with a single client
 * and broadcasting its messages.
 */
private static class Handler extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private ObjectInputStream oin;
    private ObjectOutputStream oout;
    /**
     * Constructs a handler thread, squirreling away the socket.
     * All the interesting work is done in the run method.
     */
    public Handler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /**
     * Services this thread's client by repeatedly requesting a
     * screen name until a unique one has been submitted, then
     * acknowledges the name and registers the output stream for
     * the client in a global set, then repeatedly gets inputs and
     * broadcasts them.
     */
    public void run() {
        try {

            // Create object streams for the socket.
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            oout = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


            //add socket to a list
            users.put(name,new ConnectedUsers(name,oout));
            System.err.println(users.size());
            // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
            // Ignore other clients that cannot be broadcasted to.
            while (true) {

                Object obj = oin.readObject();
                Messages message = (Messages)obj;
                if(obj.getClass().equals(Messages.class))
                {
                    for(Map.Entry<String, ConnectedUsers> entry:users.entrySet())
                    {

                            ConnectedUsers user = entry.getValue(); 
                            user.objectWriter.writeObject(message);
                    }

                }            

            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            // This client is going down!  Remove its name and its print
            // writer from the sets, and close its socket.
            if (name != null) {
                users.remove(name);
            }
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` seems to be always null so you keep using the same key (null) which would explain why there is only one user in your map.

Also note that HashMap is not thread safe - unless you add some form of synchronization when accessing the map from your threads it could yield surprising results.

You could instead use a thread safe map, for example a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: i see what you mean about those surpeising results. thanks for the help!